# How to run my node.js project on android?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, webserver

I have a working php server on my android tablet, so I hope it's available somehow to run nodejs also. The source code is available on github, and it can be build on linux also, but I can't really understand, how to build it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: A less direct way could be to use Browserify to run parts of node.js projects in Webkit.

Comment: Browserifying is only viable for projects where there is little use of Node API objects. Uses of `fs.readFileSync` will quickly become a no-go for this approach (as I've found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45209191/8295283), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45387803/8295283), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45301900/8295283) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45084751/8295283)) Now looking to: [Viable options to running NodeJS on Android (Aug 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649995/8295283)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The instructions for a build are missing from the website:

1. Download it:

   `wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.1/node-v0.8.1.tar.gz`
2. Unpack it:

   `tar xzf node-v0.8.1.tar.gz`
3. Go to the unpacked folder:

   `cd node-v0.8.1/`
4. Run

   `./configure` && `make` && `sudo make install`

You might need to install some dependencies like `g++` or `build-essential`, `curl` and `libssl-dev` first.

There is also a [packaged Android port](https://github.com/paddybyers/anode) but it doesn't seem to be actively mantained.

**edit**: apparently you need to modify some build options according to your device. A google search for "node android" + your model should give you more details. Here are they for the G1 and Galaxy S: http://mitchtech.net/node-js-on-android-linux/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a beginner, so I don't really know how to do this steps. I've searched it on google, but I haven't found any downloadable .apk file.

Comment: How does one make this approach viable as a "commercially available" solution if each distribution must be configured and built for a specific device?

Answer (score 5):

As of Sep 2015 there are Node.js 4.x distributions for ARM  from https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/

Comment: I am not sure if these ARM releases work on Android (didn't think so). My current research: [Viable options to running NodeJS on Android (Aug 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649995/8295283)