# Is there a JavaScript web server (like Node.js) for Mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, mobile, webserver

I am developing a mobile platform to turn the mobile device into a 'restful web service host' that receives requests from third parties to perform certain operation and replies back.

Since I am planning to use JQuery (javascript+HTML5+css) for the sake of portability across different mobile OSs, I need 'JavaScript web server' than java (there are couple of Java web servers for mobile devices).

Can anyone suggest any solution? I am looking for something like Tiny Java Web Server(http://tjws.sourceforge.net/) or i-jetty, but these are all written in Java.

There is something in JavaScript called Node.js, but that is a Desktop Web Server and I have no idea if I can modify it or use it in mobile devices. (I am not an experienced programmer!!!). Many thanks for your quick help in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/paddybyers/anode/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392590/how-to-run-my-node-js-project-on-android