# Is it possible to run a local web server with node.js on Android?

Tags: android, node.js, server

I am constructing a node.js application (node.js for the server side and html/javascript/css for the client side). Here is my `server.js` file:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
  fs = require('fs'),
  static = require('node-static');

// handle web server
function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client/client.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading client.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

// creating the server ( localhost:8000 )
app.listen(8000);


// Create a node-static server instance to serve the './static' folder
var staticFiles = new static.Server('./static');

require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        //
        // Serve files!
        //
        staticFiles.serve(request, response);
    }).resume();
}).listen(8080);
```

I use this as a local server to build my app. On my computer I use the command `node server.js` in Terminal to run the server and serve my html and javascript files at this address: `http://localhost:8000/`.

I would like to do the exact same thing on a tablet with android. Is this possible and how to do it?

EDIT: I have seen that maybe this is possible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392590/how-to-run-my-node-js-project-on-android) but I'm not sure that the problem is the same.

Comment: You can connect to a home server having node.js from an android app but you can't build a server in your mobile phone

Comment: @Ryan Ok but it is not an android app. So is it possible to run the node.js server on a laptop for example and to serve the files on a local address on the tablet?

Comment: What OS does your tablet have?

Comment: @Ryan It has Android

Answer (score 2):

I run Node.js on Linux on Android devices. I did it like this:

1. Install Kingroot from the Play Store to get root on the Android device.
2. Install Linux Deploy, then use it to install Fedora.
3. Use Android Terminal to su to root in Android, then run data/data/ru.meefik.com/linuxdeploy/files/bin/linuxdeploy shell to get a root shell in the Linux container.
4. Change the root password in the Linux container to 'a' (it wouldn't take more than one character for some reason).
5. Use JuiceSSH to ssh into the Fedora Linux container. Su to root and change the password.
6. dnf install nodejs npm # install node
7. npm install -g n # install substack's node version manager
8. n 5.3.0 # install v5.3.0 of node
9. mv /usr/sbin/node /usr/sbin/node.orig
10. mv /usr/sbin/npm /usr/sbin/npm.orig
11. ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/sbin/node
12. ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/sbin/npm

Steps 9 - 12 were necessary because `sudo node --version` would always return the dnf installed version, rather than the n installed version.