# Is it possible to make an android application with appium?

Tags: appium

We can do a test application with appium.But what I want is to compile the browser automation application as apk and run it on the phone.In short, can we make a bot application with appium and upload it to google play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium is Node-js based application, so if you find [a way to run it on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45733875/4103101) you can give it a try. But it sounds like a huge overhead.

I would consider native frameworks (Espresso/UIAutomator) for this purpose, but still don't think it will pass review in official google play market