# Howto use Node's stream with (or without) Typescript in React Native and VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, browserify

I am porting some Node-based packages to React Native using [ReactNativify](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify) (instead of the more 'hacky' [rn-nodeify](https://github.com/mvayngrib/rn-nodeify) method) to browserify / shim Node API object in the dependency tree. I am developing in VSCode.

With ReactNativify you use `babel-plugin-rewrite-require` in `.babelrc` (or by using javascript in a `rn-cli.config.js` + `transformer.js`):

```
{
  ...

  "plugins": [
    ["rewrite-require", {
        "aliases": {
            "constants": "constants-browserify",
            "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
            "dns": "node-libs-browser/mock/dns",
            "domain": "domain-browser",
            "stream": "stream-browserify",
            "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
            "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
            "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
            "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
            "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",

            ... etcetera
        }
    }]

    ...
}
```

(see a full example [here](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/issues/4#issuecomment-312136794))

This works rather well, and I get nice code completion / IntelliSense in VSCode, etc.

Now I want to use Node's Stream in a `MyStream.js` like so:

```
import { Duplex } from 'stream'

class MyStream extends Duplex {

  // ... implementation
}
```

The first time around this seemed to work. I got code completion, ability to 'Go to type definition`. All seemed well.

I like type safety and 'intellisense-to-the-max' so decided to convert the project / code to typescript. No problem here.

But when changing `MyStream.js` to `MyStream.ts` the IDE complained that package 'stream' was not found.

I tried various things without success, then decided to convert back to javascript, but now the - originally working - stream import was not finding the code anymore. Changing back to Typescript, now there is no error-checking at all anymore. In short, it all feels very hacky and unstable.

My questions:

- Does someone have working examples of using Node's 'stream' with React Native?
- Are there special considerations for getting code completions to work properly in VSCode (both regular ES6 + Typescript)?
- Can I use either ReactNativify or rn-nodeify in Typescript the same way as with regular js?

[Update: One thing solved. Restarting VSCode will lead it to do code validation again]

Comment: **Note**: Shimming was not viable, now looking into [Viable options for running NodeJS on Android (Aug 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649995/8295283)